# Oracle error messages

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g

I'm curious about something... is it possible for an Oracle 11 instance to be configured so that it does not return any ORA-?????? error messages?

I've issued many invalid queries where I've misspelled column names, table names... things where I would expect an ORA error message.

Say for security purposes say if a stray java stack trace got exposed to a browser could you force oracle to always show the same bogus error message in the stack trace?

I always get this one:`java.sql.SQLException: IO Error: Size Data Unit (SDU) mismatch`

I've googled that error up and down, and I do not have any connection or database configuration issues at all!  I get it on a per-query basis.

Comment: What java and oracle driver version are you using?

Comment: Java 1.5


Oracle 11g


ojdbc5.jar... its manifest file contains:

Created-By: 1.5.0_17-b02 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Implementation-Version: 11.2.0.1.0

So I'm using the same JDK and Oracle version as the driver was created with in mind.

Comment: are you sure you are connecting right?  can you get data out of tables? does "select sysdate from dual" work ok?  maybe you arent actually connected, because the database hasnt started correctly?

Comment: I am Absolutely Positive that the database is up because it's production! :)

Comment: Java 1.5? really? Now that's one legacy system...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a direct solution but I was having the same problem with the SDU mismatch masking the real error.  I found a link (http://www.rajivnarula.com/blog/2013/03/13/table-not-found-or-error-not-found/) that gave an indirect way to expose the error:

> I  tried swapping the JDBC driver with the older ojdbc14.jar and voila
>   ! The real error was exposed : Good old
>
> ORA-00942 (table or view does not exist)
>
> Once I put the table in- everything works fine- with ojdbc14.jar as
>   well ojdbc6.jar

Obviously a pain but useful until someone posts a way to get the underlying error with the newer driver...

Answer (score 2):

Basically your setup is not correct. Either on the client or on the server or on both the sdu size has been set and they do not match between client and server. The sdu size can be set on the client in

- the `sqlnet.ora` file or
- in the connect descriptor

On the server it can be set with

- in the `sqlnet.ora` file
- the dispatchers `init.ora` parameter
- or the `listener.ora` file.

If you are still not convinced, trace the tns traffic to verify this. Client side tracing can be enabled by adding the following settings to the `sqlnet.ora` file:

```
trace_level_client = 10
trace_unique_client = on
trace_file_client = sqlnet.trc
trace_directory_client = <path_to_trace_dir>
```

Server side settings can be enabled with the following settings:

```
trace_level_server = 10
trace_file_server = server.trc
trace_directory_server = <path_to_trace_dir>
```

If level `10` is not sufficient, set the level to `16`. This will create a trace file that you can analyze.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to upgrade the Oracle 11g JDBC driver to a version greater than 11.2.0.3.0, as described [here](http://albert-myptc.blogspot.ro/2012/01/io-error-size-data-unit-sdu.html)

Comment: I tried upgrad from 11.2.0.1.0 to 3.0 and there the same SDU problem

Answer (score 0):

There is another chance whether the table in the query exists in the database or not. Check for table name in the query or try whether you are trying for Oracle Database using mysql driver